# Can helicopter rotor produce infrasound?

Tags: rotorcraft, noise

While watching a Mil Mi-17 helicopter takeoff I experienced strange thing. The helicopter produces a lot of noise even when just starting the engines.

But shortly before taking off the high-pitched sound of the jet engines changed somehow (I guess changing the tilt of the rotor blades) and I felt some sort o pulsing "sound" which I felt rather with my belly than with my ears. Really unpleasant experience.

Could it be infrasound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Each rotor blade produces a pressure wave. Here's an [example from a Chinook](https://amateurgeophysics.wordpress.com/the-analysis-of-sound-using-raven-lite-software/4-the-analysis-of-sound-twin-rotor-chinook-helicopter/):

[image]

At a rotor speed of 4 rotations per second, that's 12 pressure spikes per second, or a frequency of 12 Hz. At frequencies that low, you can hear the individual waves rather than a coherent tone (try this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA7Qa6tfA6k) on a good set of headphones).

At high levels you tend to feel more than hear this frequency: you can feel the pressure variations on your skin, your eardrums and in your lungs, and you could get resonances in your body.